# Qt 4.x/5.x and OpenGL for Desktop Gui application: What module to choose?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am starting a new GUI application project using Qt and OpenGL for Linux/Windows desktops. My assumptions so far: use Qt GUI (C++ ... not QML/QtQuick 2) with OpenGL 4.1 or higher (requirement). After some reading, I am completely lost about what path to choose. What path will keep my application future-proof in term of support and libraries.

Qt 4.x or Qt 5.x?
Standard OpenGL or QGL or QOpenGL or QtOpenGL wrappers?
QWidget/QGLWidget (Qt 4.x) or QWindow (Qt 5.x)?

The application is intended to run in desktop environment and will do a lot of file (geometry) opening/saving, instanced 3D painting and some imaging. Could someone point me out to the best combination to choose with some explanation if possible?

Sean Harmer [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYa5DLV6ADQ) on Qt 5 and OpenGL did answer some parts of my questions but I was a bit lost when he started using QML and QtQuick 2. I felt like QOpenGL was a lightweighted version to be used with QtQuick 2. Correct me If I am wrong on that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt 5.0 is still in beta, therefore if your project is serious, you should go with qt 4.8, because that is the latest stable release. However, if you must have some Qt 5.0 features, then you have no other choice but to go with 5.0.

Since you chosen Qt, you should stick to it. That means using QtOpenGL. That doesn't mean you are not going to use standard OpenGL. QtOpenGL provides you API to simplify some OpenGL calls, and make them more object oriented. After all, OpenGL is set of C functions, not set of c++ classes.

Comment: Thank you BЈовић. I will give it a start with QtOpenGL module/Qt 4.8 and port the code to Qt 5.0 (in the future) as some QtOpenGL-related issues are intended to be fixed in Qt 5.1.

Comment: From the other hand,if you are new to OpenGL and want to understand the API then use the API directly.

Comment: @MichaelIV But to use opengl's API directly, I wouldn't use Qt. I would use SDL or glut to create a window.

Comment: Not at all.I use Qt with "pure " OpenGL API because of its GUI capabilities which are non existent in GLUT.I tried Qt GL API and to me it looks too much abstraction...